# Como fazer uma "formatação condicional hierarquizada" no Excel 2010?

Tags: microsoft-excel, formatação-condicional

eu preciso programar uma "formatação condicional hierarquizada" no Excel 2010, com base em duas entradas: o formato da célula à esquerda e se o valor pertence ou não a um dado intervalo.

Para entender melhor do que eu preciso, suponha que eu esteja na célula B1.

Pude definir a primeira condição, cliquei em  clicando em "Usar uma fórmula para determinar quais células devem ser formatadas" e digitei = CÉL ("formato"; A1) = "P1", pois preciso saber se A1 é ou não uma porcentagem.

Além disso, consigo definir a segunda condição clicando em "Formatar apenas células que contenham" e depois em "entre", por exemplo, 0,5 e 0,6.

O problema é que o intervalo desejado depende do formato da célula à esquerda. Por isso, eu queria definir algo assim:

Se (A1 for porcentagem) E (B1 estiver entre 0,5 e 0,6), aplique o formato selecionado.

Se (A1 não for porcentagem) ED (B1 estiver entre 5 e 6), aplique o formato selecionado.

Tentei selecionar "Use uma fórmula para determinar quais células devem ser formatadas" e digite a fórmula abaixo, mas não funcionou!

= E (CÉL ("formato"; A1) = "P1"; AND ("B1> 0,5"; "B1 <0,6"))

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Desde já, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boa noite amigo, tudo bem?

Verifica como está o seu campo de porcentagem, pois em alguns casos dependendo da quantidade de casas decimais, a função (CÉL + Formato) pode te trazer outros retornos.

Veja o exemplo de vários retornos na imagem abaixo:

Outro ponto, acredito que sua condicional esteja incorreta.
Tente implementar a fórmula conforme abaixo:

[image: Retornos da Função (CÉL+FORMATO) + Fórmula completa]

Fórmula completa:

```
=OU(E(OU(CÉL("formato";B7)="P0";CÉL("formato";B7)="P1";);E7>=0,5;E7<=0,6);E(OU(CÉL("formato";B7)="G";CÉL("formato";B7)="F0";CÉL("formato";B7)="F1";);E7>=5;E7<=6))
```

Comment: Ajudou muito! Obrigado!